# Android POPUP Code

Tags: android, popup

I would need an example code to create a popup in an activity. In the popup I would like to insert a number in a edittext and return it to the main activity.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look an Google for this kind of questions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog